# DoesNotExist at /api/v1/mlalgorithms MLAlgorithmStatus matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class MLAlgorithmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    current_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_current_status(self, mlalgorithm):
        return MLAlgorithmStatus.objects.filter(parent_mlalgorithm=mlalgorithm).latest('created_at').status

    class Meta:
        model = MLAlgorithm
        read_only_fields = ("id", "name", "description", "code",
                            "version", "owner", "created_at",
                            "parent_endpoint", "current_status")
        fields = read_only_fields
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
return Response(serializer.data)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
ret = super().data
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
return [
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 687, in 
self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 522, in to_representation
ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1838, in to_representation
return method(value)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/dpmlex1/endpoints/serializers.py", line 16, in get_current_status
return MLAlgorithmStatus.objects.filter(parent_mlalgorithm=mlalgorithm).latest('created_at').status
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in latest
return self.reverse()._earliest(*fields)
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1028, in _earliest
return obj.get()
File "/Users/dpashraful/PycharmProjects/Dpml_ex1/exer_1/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /api/v1/mlalgorithms
Exception Value: MLAlgorithmStatus matching query does not exist.

I had every solution that was available in Stackoverflow but could not solve it. where is the issue?